# Using "must" to express probability with high degree of certainty

Tags: modal-verbs

> The army often just can't tell who the Taliban are, and whoever dreamed up these hare-brained interviews ***must not have*** seen the extensive media coverage of "collateral damage" in 2012.

As far as I understand from the context, the journalist uses "must" as if s/he is pretty certain that those who dreamed up have not seen the extensive media coverage of "collateral damage" in 2012. (Sorry for the terrible wording!)

Is it common to use "must" in this way? Is there an alternative form to express the same meaning, perhaps using "might"?

Comment: Yes, it's common.  See [sense 5b](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/must) in the AHD.  I can't think of a good paraphrase off the top of my head, so I can't answer just yet, but I'm not sure it's possible to use *might* here.  I don't think *might* is certain enough.

Comment: @Carlo: If you substitute "might", you're [potentially radically] changing the meaning. As it stands, the writer is *certain* of what he says. With "might", he'd only be advancing a *possible* explanation (which he could then go on to dismiss as something he doesn't actually believe anyway).

Comment: *might* is impossible, but *cannot have seen* works.

Comment: The only one to me that implies absolute certainty is "didn't see".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a valid use - it is used to imply a deduction:

> I see that the window is open and my TV is missing, so I **must have been** robbed.
>
> If the lights were on, they **must've been** home.
>
> Inevitably we all **must** die.

Comment: I agree with the sense of deduction in the first two sentences in your answer, but not the third one.